# Set content-type to application/octet-stream for all files in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to AWS S3 bucket I am trying to set permission of all the files to directly download. I don't want my video or images to open in browser. I just want it to be directly download.

Here is how my file permissions are set.

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way to set **`Content-Type : application/octet-stream`** for all the files.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Response headers have nothing to do with permissions.

If you want specific `Content-Type` or `Content-Disposition` headers for your files you can specify them in objects metadata like this:

[image]

See full tutorial from AWS here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-object-metadata.html

When you upload your files, for example with [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-object.html), you can specify `Content-Type` at the same time:

> aws s3api put-object [--acl ] [--body ]
>   --bucket  [--cache-control ] [--content-disposition ] [--content-encoding ] [--content-language ]
>   [--content-length ] [--content-md5 ] [--content-type
>   ] ...

SDKs provide similar functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The thing is, we are uploading the videos directly from S3 bucket, we are not using CLI for this. And changing permission of all the individual file upload is not possible. So we can get something better here that will be really helpful.

Comment: Does the bucket belong to you or not? If it does, you can change response headers no matter what method you use to upload. If it doesn't, you can't override headers on other people's files.

Comment: Yes thats belong to me. How can I change the response header?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I came to know either you have no control over the files that are coming in or making modifications to the code or service which pushes content to s3 might not be that easy. Whatever, my choice would be to implement a lambda which is triggered by s3:object created which just uses the AWS.S3:copyobject with source and destination same, but metadata as response-content-type application/octect-stream and response-content-disposition attachment. Once the lambda is in place, should use the AWS CLI to recursively copy existing files with the new metadata on existing files.

Better refers the AWS documents for lambda and corresponding SDK references. Check out the AWS repository on git and you may find something which goes in the same track.